# Angular4 router.navigate doesn't do anything

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the conditional navigation based on customers role in the system. Something like this:

```
this.GetQuickStartStatus()
                    .subscribe(data => {
                            if(data.isActive){
                                this.storageService.Store('isQuick', "true");
                            }
                            else{
                                this.storageService.Store('isQuick', "false");
                            }

                            if(this.storageService.Retrieve("Role") === "user"){
                                console.log("package");
                                this.router.navigate(['/packages']);
                            }

                            if(this.storageService.Retrieve("Role") === "subscriber" && this.storageService.Retrieve("isQuick") === "false"){
                                console.log("quickstart");
                                this.router.navigate(['/quickstart']);
                            }
                            console.log("nothing");
                            this.router.navigate(['']);
                    }, (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
```

I log with the new user which should redirect to packages page since users role is "user. I get his in the console:

> auth.service.ts:156 package
>   auth.service.ts:164 nothing

The meaning condition gets hit, but doesn't do anything aka router doesn't navigate to the requested page. I checked all conditions are met and all values are stored in localstorage. Why would router.navigate ignore redirection?

Routing module for packages:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: 'packages', component: PackageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
        { path: 'receipt', component: PackageReceiptComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService, RoleSubscriberGuardService] },
        { path: 'receipt/:token', component: PackageReceiptComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService, RoleSubscriberGuardService]}
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PackageRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Share your routing module?

Comment: Problem isn't located here: this.router.navigate(['']); ? This line is executed every time. Try to commend it or wrap with `else`

Comment: I appended for packages. I have them segregated

Comment: Have you tried navigating to "/" instead of just ""?

Comment: @MaciejTreder can you please put is an answer, that was it, not sure how it worked in first try probably because of cache. clean your cache people.

Comment: @AmelSalibasic Sure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `this.router.navigate(['']);` at the end of your method - which is executed every time.

Try to wrap this line in the `else` block.